# How to evenly space round ImageButtons with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I have found how to create round ImageButtons using a `Shape` background and I have found how to evenly space buttons in a LinearLayout by setting the width to 0dp and the weight to 1. But I can't combine both, so either the round buttons are not evenly spaced
[image: round but not evenly spaced]

or they are evenly spaced but not round
[image]

It seems the extra space is going to the inside button instead of to the margins. How can I make a `LinearLayout` allocate the new empty space to margins and not to the view?

This is the layout that gives me the second image above

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
  <solid android:color="#33DDFF" />
  <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Using a `ConstraintsLayout` will be easier in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution I found was to use empty `Space`s around and in between the buttons and have those take the extra space

```
    <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Space>
```

I had to remove the weight from the actual buttons and set the width to `wrap_content`

```
 <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"

            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:contentDescription="@string/speak_button_desc"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

Step 1: Set the android:layout_width="0dp"
Step 2: Set the android:layout_weight equally among all button with sum equal to 1.0

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<ImageButton 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/clear"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight=".5" />

 <ImageButton 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/submit" 
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight=".5" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great! Except for that it is not necessary to set the layout_width equal to 1 in sum. It is important to set the same weight for all the buttons. (It could be 1, 1, 1 for 3 buttons, for example)